# Solve for x: $2^{3x} + 8 \cdot 2^{2x} - 6 \cdot 2^{2x} = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve this equality for x:$$2^{3x} + 8 \cdot 2^{2x} - 6 \cdot 2^{2x} = 0$$

Comment: Take $2^x=t$ and go ahead

Comment: $8\cdot 2^x-6\cdot 2^x=2\cdot 2^x$

Comment: Is $2^{3x} + 8 \cdot 2^{2x} - 6 \cdot 2^{2x}$ ever equal to $0$?

Answer (score 5):

Divide by $2^{2x}$ ($\ne0$).

$$2^x+8-6=0$$ shouldn't be too hard to investigate.

Comment: Love the fact you wrote *investigate* instead of *solve*. The equation is indeed easy to investigate, but impossible to solve (in the reals)